# Bootstrap multi select : Flag to check all options are selected or not

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using  bootstrap multiselect plugin to enable the filtering of a select control and multiple selection .
I have to load another dropdown based on the selected values and i used the

> onDropdownHide

event for doing the same

The code looks like this

```
$("#@param_name").multiselect({
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    includeResetOption: true,
    includeResetDivider: true,
    resetText: "Reset all",
    selectAllValue: 'select-all-value',
    onDropdownHide: function (event) {                                              
        var allselected= ?????;   
        callTargetDropDownLoad(allselected);
    }
});
```

And based on the allselected variable i have to write some custom logics. But i am not seeing any way to identify all values are selected or not in the dropdown and assign it to

```
 allselected variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the classical [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
$('#\\@param_name option:selected')  // get all selected options
```

If, instead, you need to check if all options is selected you can use:

```
this.$ul.find('li.multiselect-all').is('.active');  // check if the selectall is selected
```

```js
$("#\\@param_name").multiselect({
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    includeResetOption: true,
    includeResetDivider: true,
    resetText: "Reset all",
    selectAllValue: 'select-all-value',
    onDropdownHide: function (event) {
        var isMultiSelected = this.$ul.find('li.multiselect-all').is('.active');
console.log('multiselect ---> ' + isMultiSelected );
        var allselected= $('#\\@param_name option:selected');
        allselected.each((a,b) => console.log(b.textContent));
        callTargetDropDownLoad(allselected);
    }
});

function callTargetDropDownLoad(a) {
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>


<select id="@param_name" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does the selectAllValue had any impact on this

Comment: From the plugin properties we will get an additional property or setting called selectAllValue  . I am not been able to find the importance of this one

Comment: Yes , the code  var isMultiSelected = this.$ul.find('li.multiselect-all').is('.active'); will return true or false. But not sure about the line of code  var allselected= $('#\\@param_name option:selected');

Comment: The first line (in my answer) returns all the selected options while the second returns if multiselect-all is checked.